# How to solve django.url.exceptions.NoReverseMatch with kwargs?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to update an object that has already been created.

Following is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include, path

from rest_framework import routers

from . import admin_views, temp_views, views

app_name = "transactions"


router = routers.SimpleRouter()

router.register(r"transactions", views.TransactionViewSet)
router.register(r"offerings", views.OfferingViewSet)
router.register(r"bank_accounts", views.BankAccountViewSet)
router.register(r"merchants", views.MerchantViewSet)
```

Following is my views.py:

```
class MerchantViewSet(GetPrefixedIDMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """POST support for /merchants/."""
    print ("in MerchantViewSet")
    queryset = models.Merchant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CreateMerchantSerializer
    lookup_field = "id"
    lookup_value_regex = f"{models.Merchant.id_prefix}_[a-f0-9]{32}"
    permission_classes = [permissions.MerchantPermission]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Filter the queryset based on the full merchant name or starting with a letter."""
        queryset = models.Merchant.objects.all()
        search_param = self.request.query_params.get("search", None)
        if search_param:
            if search_param.startswith("^"):
                queryset = queryset.filter(name__istartswith=search_param[1:])
            else:
                queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=search_param)
        return queryset
```

Following is the test I am trying to write:

```
class MerchantsViewSetTest(tests.BigETestCase):  # noqa

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):  # noqa

        super(MerchantsViewSetTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.application = tests.get_application()
        tests.create_group("merchant")
        cls.consumer_user = tests.create_consumer()
        cls.admin = tests.create_administrator()

        cls.merchant_geraldine = models.Merchant.objects.create(
            name="Test Account 1",
            contact_name="Geraldine Groves",
            contact_email="geraldine@example.com",
            contact_phone_number="+35310000000",
        )

        cls. merchant_barbara = models.Merchant.objects.create(
            name="Account 2",
            contact_name="Barbara",
            contact_email="barbara@example.com",
            contact_phone_number="+35310000432",
        )

 def test_edit_merchant(self): # noqa
        # url = reverse("bige_transactions:merchant-list", kwargs={"id": self.merchant_geraldine.prefixed_id},)
        url = reverse("bige_transactions:merchant-list", kwargs={"id": self.merchant_geraldine.prefixed_id})
        # payload
        data = {"name": "Edited"}

        # verify anonymous cannot edit a user
        self.put(url, data, status_code=401)
```

Following is my permissions.py:

```
class MerchantPermission(BasePermission):  # noqa

def _has_get_permission(self, request, view):  # noqa
    access_token = get_access_token(request)
    # we allow the request if the user is an admin
    if is_administrator(access_token.user):
        return True

    return False

def _has_put_permission(self, request, view):  # noqa
    print ("entered put permissions")
    access_token = get_access_token(request)
    # we allow the request if the user is an admin
    if is_administrator(access_token.user):
        print ("Admin detected!")
        return True

    return False

def has_permission(self, request, view):  # noqa
    # is it a supported method
    method = request.method.lower()
    if method in view.http_method_names:
        if method == "post":
            return True
        elif method == "get":
            return self._has_get_permission(request, view)
        elif method == "put":
            return self._has_put_permission(request, view)
    # always deny by default
    raise exceptions.MethodNotAllowed(request.method)
```

So basically what I am trying to do is to add a functionality whereby I can update a merchant's detail. From my understanding from reading the Django Rest Framework documentation, the router.register method in my urls.py should set up all the URL's for create, list, update, retrieve and destroy. With my current test method, I get :

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'merchant-list' with keyword arguments '{'id': 'merch_b6c983ec082b4c7eb321b335fe9b122c'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['merchants/$']
```

I am able to create, list and search users (didn't add those methods here as they are not relevant and don't want to make this question longer than it needs to be). I changing the url to

```
url = reverse("bige_transactions:merchant-list") + "?id=" + self.merchant_geraldine.prefixed_id
```

which does print out the URL, and I do not get the reverse() method error anymore, but I get a 404 error. So I am kind of stuck trying to implement this and I cannot find any examples on how to use the update() method that is built in ModelViewSet other than mentions of that it can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register your viewset using `router.register(r"merchants", views.MerchantViewSet)` behind the scene you will get two different reverse urls:

`merchants-list` -> actual url will be `^merchants/$`

`merchants-detail` -> actual url will be `^merchants/<pk>/$`

In your case since you defined `lookup_field="id"` if might be `<id>` instead of `<pk>`. So your code needs to use the detail url like this:

```
url = reverse("bige_transactions:merchant-detail", kwargs={'id': self.merchant_geraldine.prefixed_id})
```

For more info check related [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage)